# PsExec : Can't find the file specified

Tags: psexec

I am not sure why the below does not work for me.

```
psexec \\remote -u DOMAIN\UID -p PWD F:\1.txt -i
psexec \\remote -u DOMAIN\UID -p PWD "F:\1.txt" -i
psexec -s -accepteula \\remote -u DOMAIN\UID -p PWD F:\1.txt -i
```

result : psexec starts, says F:\1.txt : system can't find the file specified.

1. The user is an admin on remote
2. F:\1.txt exists and has some text
3. i have tried -accepteula and -s as well.

Still scratching my head. Finally up to some gentleman to guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the PWD in this command line for.  Is it a batch script or an executable?  Reminds me of the Unix pwd shell command?

Psexec needs the full path to any commands or files you want to use.  Also, the path is the remote machines path, not machine from your local console.

I usually do something like this
psexec \remote -u DOMAIN\UID -p cmd /c "PWD F:\1.txt -i"

You have to use quotes around the command to run.